# Search for field name in text file and return all subsequent lines to console - C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to create a function that will scan through a text file for a specific field name and return all subsequent lines of text to the console.

The text file looks like this :

```
----8896484051606557286
Content-Type: text/html;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7Bit

<html>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<div style="border-color: #00FFFF; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-   width: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" align="center">
<table style="border: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color:#000000;"  cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCFFAA">
<tr>
<td style="border: 0px; border-bottom: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color:#000000;">
<center>

----8896484051606557286--
```

I want to search for the field name 'Content-Type: text/html or Content-Type: text/plain' and return the text following that between the boundary marker (----8896484051606557286--).

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string path = "C:/TEST/";
    string common = "SPAM";

    for (int count = 1; count <= 100; ++count) {
        //Convert count to an string.
        stringstream ss;
        ss << count;
        string numstring = ss.str();
        string filename = path + common + numstring + ".txt.";

        ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
        string line;
        string CT1 = "Content-Type: text/html";
        string CT2 = "Content-Type: text/plain";

        while (!infile.eof()) {
            getline(infile, line);
            int index = fileStr.find("Content-Type:", 0)

            if (index >= 0) {
                index += 13;
            } //(just add the size of Content - Type:)
            int endIndex = fileString.find(";", index)
                           string contentType = fileString.subString(index, endIndex index);
            if (contentType.compare("text/html") == 0) {
                // then parse as text / html //
            } else if (contentType.compare("text/plain") == 0) {
                 //parse as the text/html'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I correct my code to search for Content-Type (either text/html or text/plain) and return the all of the subsequent lines between the the boundary markers ?

Comment: thanks for sharing your coding attempt but what exactly do you need help with - there is no actual question in here

Comment: And your question is? - I presume you are not asking "Can someone write the code in // then parse as text/html", as this is not a "write code service", but a question and answer type site.

Comment: Sorry - this is my first time using this site. My question is how do I correct my code to search for Content-Type (either text/html or text/plain) and return all of the subsequent lines between the boundary markers? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
// ...
std::string keyword;
std::string word;

getline(file, keyword);
do
{
    std::cin >> word;
}
while (keyword.find(word) == std::string::npos);
```

Comment: I don't want to use cin as I need to scan through a directory with over 70,000 files. I need the function to read through each file in the directory find either "Content-Type: text/html" or "Content-Type: text/plain" and return all of the text between the boundary marker and ignore all of the other text in the file.

The program will eventually tokenise all of the string data between the boundary markers and store them in a vector/array ready to form a connection with an SQlite database. I'm just struggling at the first hurdle. thanks

Comment: @TheBlueNile `find . -type f -exec yourapp '{}' \;`

Comment: @Erbureth - could you expand that explanation a little bit as I'm somewhat of a newbie when it comes to coding C++. Perhaps put it into the context of my code... Many thanks

Comment: @TheBlueNile You don't have to code the directory listing into your app, you just need to write your code to process one file and then use external [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) tool to pass the files as parameters to your app.

Comment: @Erbureth Thanks for the suggestion. I'm still struggling to write the code to process one file...

Comment: Any other suggestions? Anyone? :) Thanks